# ¿Como mostrar un checkbox si una variable tiene texto, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Buen día.
Existe una variable con valor que responde el servidor.
puede venir así:

```
DescripcionProductoGratis = ""
```

o así:

```
DescripcionProductoGratis: "Tienes  Derecho a un Producto con Valor de: 460 - 9588 Lima de Pies"
```

Entonces si la variable DescripcionProductoGratis tiene algun contenido debo mostrar un div que contiene un checkbox, para lo cual lo estoy realizando de esta forma:

```
if (response.data.DescripcionProductoGratis){
    $('.lista-productogratis').show();
    $('.DescripcionProductoGratis').html(response.data.DescripcionProductoGratis);
}
```

pero no me funciona.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Acá el div que he utilizado:

```
<div class="list-block no-hairlines no-hairlines-between lista-productogratis">
                    <div class="card data-table data-table-init">
                        <form id="productoGratis">
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label-cell" style="padding: 0 !important;">
                                              <label class="label-checkbox item-content">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="productogratis" class="productogratis" />
                                                <span class="item-media">
                                                    <i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>
                                                </span>
                                                <span class="item-inner">
                                                    <span class="item-title DescripcionProductoGratis"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody></tbody>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var response = "";
 if (response !=""){
    $('.lista-productogratis').show();
    $('.DescripcionProductoGratis').html("pruebaaa");
}
else
{
    $('.lista-productogratis').hide();
    $('.DescripcionProductoGratis').html("pruebaaa");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lista-productogratis">
                    <div class="card data-table data-table-init">
                        <form id="productoGratis">
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="label-cell" style="padding: 0 !important;">
                                              <label class="label-checkbox item-content">
                                                <input type="checkbox" id="productogratis" class="productogratis" />
                                                <span class="item-media">
                                                    <i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>
                                                </span>
                                                <span class="item-inner">
                                                    <span class="item-title DescripcionProductoGratis"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody></tbody>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Intenta comprobando que sea distinto de vacio debido a las dos opciones que muestras de la respuesta que podria traer del servidor, de lo contrario se esconde:

```
  if (response.data.DescripcionProductoGratis != ""){
        $('.lista-productogratis').show();
        $('.DescripcionProductoGratis').html(response.data.DescripcionProductoGratis);
    }else {
$('.lista-productogratis').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el problema se encuentra en el if

```
if (response.data.DescripcionProductoGratis.length > 0){
    $('.lista-productogratis').show();
    $('.DescripcionProductoGratis').html(response.data.DescripcionProductoGratis);
}
```

Esto lo deberia solucionar el problema, verificar la longitud del texto, si el string tiene una longitud mayor a 0 se va a mostrar